# PHP5 to PHP7 if test difference in switch case

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.5

I have recently upgraded from PHP5 to PHP7.
This gave me an error. After distilling the problem I was able to fix. However I still found it a weird problem.

Given the following code:

```
<?php

$r = "R";
$a = false;

switch ($r) {
  case "R":
  default:
    // Test 1
    if($a){
      echo("error;");
    }else{
      echo("working;");
    }
    // Test 2
    if($a !== false){
      echo("error;");
    }else{
      echo("working;");
    }
    break;
}
?>
```

The output of this code is:
PHP 5.5.9:

```
working;working;
```

PHP 7.0.13:

```
error;working;
```

**Why is this difference there?**

However when removing the switch case block around 'Test 1', this result in `working`.

Changing the initial declaration of `$r` to something else then 'R' also results in `working;working;`. This means that depending on if we start from 'case' or from 'default' the result is different.

When adding the line `var_dump($a);` in front of the 'Test 1' (inside the switch case) it results in `bool(false) working;working;`

Odd observation:
When running the code for the first time it sometimes result in: `working;working;` and by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> it results in `error;working;` again.

**Why does it react differently in this way?**

My best guess it that this has something to do with type conversion.

Comment: This code seems to print `working;working;` for me on PHP 7.0.12.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my local system or here: https://3v4l.org/Q7eph

Comment: I'm always getting the same output(`working;working;`), no matter which verson I choose in [this sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/).

Comment: Here is my test page: https://ralphbisschops.com/test.php (same code as above) running on PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: reinstalling libapache2-mod-php7.0 and php7.0 did not change anything (same version)

Comment: It works for me too. On both versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved this problem. 
But after regular updates on the server it got solved at some point.

It probably was a problem in php somewhere as I did not update the page, but it is solved now.

( running PHP 7.2.24 now )
So just update your php version if you have this problem.